# How to set the views variables in a Node.js+Express vertical structure project?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I decided to adopt a vertical structure for my *Node.js+Express* project, as a consequence I have sub-projects/sub-folders (*User management, Cart, Inventory*) by feature:

```
Project
--core
----views
----(...)
--usermgmt
----views
```

and obviously controllers, routes, models and views are defined for every feature. 
My problem now is how to set the views directory for the project. I mean when I do that in horizontal structure, I write:

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
```

It is easy since the views directory is unique

but now, I have many views directories so I don't know what the best practice is. For the moment, I set the variable views `to __dirname` and when I render I go from the root directory to the corresponding one.

Any advice?

Comment: Please refer MEAN JS that may give you some knowledge http://meanjs.org/

Answer (score 1):

I'd quote from the documentation itself.

> A directory or an array of directories for the application's views. If
>   an array, the views are looked up in the order they occur in the
>   array.

http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.set
(Scroll down and find `views` in table just below)

[image]

OR

You can create each of your `feature` as separate app (just don't do `app.listen`) then in your master app you can do something like this

> Launch.js

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var http = require('http');
var app = require('express')();

app.use('/feature1',require('./feature1');
app.use('/feature2',require('./feature2');

// Setup port
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.set('port', port);

 //Create HTTP server.

var server = http.createServer(app);


//Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
server.listen(port);

server.on('listening', function(){
   var addr = server.address();
   var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;

  //You can open browser -- uncomment below line
  //require("openurl").open("http://localhost:3000");

  debug('Magic happens at : http://localhost:' + addr.port); 
});
```

Your `feature` directories would contain an index.js which would do ...

> .js
>       var express = require('express');
>       var path = require('path');
>       var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
>       var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

```
var settings = require('./lib/settings');

//Import your routes
var defRoute = require('./defRoute');
var users = require('./users');
var someOtherResource = require('./someOtherResource');    

var app = express();

// view engine setup
//This sets view for `this` app to relative `views` folder
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


//Mount your routes
app.use('/',defRoute);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/someOtherResource', someOtherResource')

//Other awesome code

//Return this app.
module.exports = app;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! So, it works well with using a directory of views. I will try the second option while I will do a major refactoring

mph